# list of white pixels indices in image using CUDA

Tags: c++, image-processing, cuda

Given a binary image, I want to return the list of indices for white pixels in it using GPU (Compute Unified Device Architecture). How to determine the index for points vector?
Here is the CUDA Kernel .

```
//copy only active pixel locations

__global__ void get_white_pixels_kernel(unsigned char* bin_image,
float * points,
int width,
int height,
int grayWidthStep)
{

int row_index = threadIdx.y+ blockIdx.y*blockDim.y;
int col_index = threadIdx.x+blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
if ((col_index < width) && (row_index < height))
{

    //Location of gray pixel in output
    const int gray_tid = row_index * grayWidthStep + col_index;
    if(input[gray_tid]==255)
       points[--here is the index]= Point2f(row_index,col_index);

}

}
```

Comment: And I want a sandwich. Did you have an actual question to ask?

Comment: What is your question OP? O_o and how is pt defined?

Comment: i want list of indices for white pixels using CUDA

Comment: @AhmedNady Well, what have you done so far? You should start with http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html

Comment: Repeatedly telling us what you want isn't the same thing as asking a valid question on [SO]. We are not a free code writing service. If you have been attempting to do this yourself and have a problem, ask a question about that problem. You might receive an answer which helps you

Comment: @Ash, Thanks for your help, but what i want determine the index for points in vector in cuda kernal ..

Comment: @talonmies, thanks for your advice. but my question is how to determine the index for vector of points in cuda kernel.

Comment: BTW, this was a good question you just needed to write it more clearly. The gatekeepers are a little harsh -- don't be discouraged by them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is a naive method to achieve the desired functionality:

- Generate a mask of pixel indices with dummy values for pixel with zero value.
- Count the number of non-zero pixels
- Create an output vector with length equal to non-zero count.
- Copy the non-zero pixel indices from the generated mask to the output vector (a process known as stream-compaction)

Following is a sample code for the above mentioned process.

## Code

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <thrust/count.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>


static void _check_err(cudaError_t err, const char* file, int line)
{
    if(err)
    {
        const char* err_str = cudaGetErrorString(err);

        printf("CUDA Error: %s\nFile: %s\nLine: %d\n", err_str, file, line);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

#define CHECK_ERR(err) _check_err((err), __FILE__, __LINE__)



__global__ void kernel_find_indices(const unsigned char* input, int width, int height, int step, int2* indices)
{
    const int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    const int y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    if(x < width && y < height)
    {
        const int tidPixel = y * step + x;
        const int tidIndex = y * width + x;

        unsigned char value = input[tidPixel];

        int2 index_to_write;


        if(value)
        {
            //Write actual index to pixels with non-zero value
            index_to_write.x = x;
            index_to_write.y = y;
        }
        else
        {
            //Write dummy index to pixels with zero value
            index_to_write.x = -1;
            index_to_write.y = -1;
        }

        indices[tidIndex] = index_to_write;
    }
}


//Operator to check whether an index is of a non-zero pixel
struct isNonZeroIndex
{
  __host__ __device__ bool operator()(const int2 &idx)
  {
    return (idx.x != -1) && (idx.y != -1);
  }
};


std::vector<cv::Point> getIndicesOfNonZeroPixels(cv::Mat input)
{
    std::vector<int2> output_int2;
    std::vector<cv::Point> output;

    int pixelCount = input.cols * input.rows;
    size_t imageBytes=  input.step * input.rows;

    unsigned char* image_d;
    thrust::device_vector<int2> index_buffer_d(pixelCount);

    //Allocate device memory for input image
    CHECK_ERR(cudaMalloc(&image_d, imageBytes));
    //Copy input image to device
    CHECK_ERR(cudaMemcpy(image_d, input.ptr(), imageBytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    dim3 block(16,16);
    dim3 grid;
    grid.x = (input.cols + block.x - 1) / block.x;
    grid.y = (input.rows + block.y - 1) / block.y;

    //Generate an index mask with dummy values for indices with zero pixel value
    kernel_find_indices<<<grid, block>>>(image_d, input.cols, input.rows, input.step, thrust::raw_pointer_cast(index_buffer_d.data()));
    CHECK_ERR(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    int nonZeroCount = thrust::count_if(index_buffer_d.begin(), index_buffer_d.end(), isNonZeroIndex());

    //Keep only those indices whose pixel value is non-zero (stream compaction)
    thrust::device_vector<int2> compacted(nonZeroCount);
    thrust::copy_if(index_buffer_d.begin(), index_buffer_d.end(), compacted.begin(), isNonZeroIndex());

    //Copy non-zero pixel indices to host
    output_int2.resize(nonZeroCount);
    thrust::copy(compacted.begin(), compacted.end(), output_int2.begin());

    CHECK_ERR(cudaFree(image_d));

    //Convert vector<int2> to vector<cv::Point>
    output.resize(nonZeroCount);
    for(size_t i=0; i<nonZeroCount; i++)
        output[i] = cv::Point(output_int2[i].x, output_int2[i].y);

    return output;
}

void run_test()
{
    //Generate a sample test image
    cv::Mat test = cv::Mat::zeros(100,100, CV_8UC1);
    cv::rectangle(test, cv::Rect(5,5,20,20), cv::Scalar::all(255), CV_FILLED);

    //Get pixel indices of non-zero pixels
    std::vector<cv::Point> indices = getIndicesOfNonZeroPixels(test);

    //Display those indices
    for(size_t i=0; i<indices.size(); i++)
    {
        printf("%d, %d\n", indices[i].x, indices[i].y);
    }

    //Show image
    cv::imshow("Sample", test);
    cv::waitKey();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    run_test();
    return 0;
}
```

## Compilation Command

> nvcc -o nz nz.cu -arch=sm_61 -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core
>   -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc

Please keep in mind that this code is for image of type `8UC1` (8 bit, single channel) only. You can easily extend it to other data-types as required.

Comment: thanks for your efforts. that's i want. but there  is a way for achieving this (find_indices) with cuda kernel only ?

Comment: As far as I know, keeping ONLY the required indices is a problem which requires launching multiple kernels (as done currently). The calls to `thrust` (with device pointer arguments) are also kernels or memory copies at the backend. As I have mentioned before, this is just a naive implementation and may have quite a potential for optimization.

Comment: Excellent answer. Doesn't seem to naive to me, although it seems that the mask creation and copy_if could be done in the same step (?)